# how to identify the usage of an specific sql login

Tags: sql-server

I'm examining a Database Server which have several sql logins.there is a specific sql login with sysadmin server Role which i can't find where exactly is its usage. On sp_who2 result this login is used with BACKGROUND status which is running commands Like LOG WRITER ,RECOVERY WRITER,LAZY WRITER,XE TIMER,TRACE QUEUE TASK,TRACE QUEUE TASK &c.

Now I want to know where is the usage of this SQL Login, because I want to change its password.

Comment: You can [turn on login auditing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175850.aspx) so it records all logins, including successful ones.  Then you can look at the SQL Server error log to see where the login is coming from.  After you figure it out, turn login auditing off, or at least back to "just failed logins".

Comment: certainly its usage is on a specific system service. i have check regular services like SQL Engine and SQL Agent and and it's not there

Comment: Check the is_user_process column of sys.dm_exec_sessions to see if any of those are system sessions rather than user sessions.  If you want further assistance, please post the output of sp_who2, sys.dm_exec_sessions, sys.dm_exec_connections, and whatever else you're using for diagnosis.

Comment: Dear Anti-weakpassword, all of the sessions from that specific user are system process which means is_user_process is set to 0

Answer (score 0):

As all the sessions for that user are system processes per your comment, this is the system itself, i.e. the "sa" account and/or the SQL Server Service account using Trusted Authentication.